# Apply a function to each element of a list and sum it

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
{-1.8, 1.44, 0.2736, -1.72514, 1.17612}
```

where each element stands for a value of x. e.g. $x1 = -1.8$, $x2 = 1.44$ and so on.

How can I find the summation of $ln(2x)$ without manuall calculating it? That is: $ln(2(-1.8)) + ln(2(1.44)) + \ldots + ln(2(1.17612))$

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {-1.8, 1.44, 0.2736, -1.72514, 1.17612};
Plus @@ Log[2 list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {-1.8, 1.44, 0.2736, -1.72514, 1.17612};
Total[Log[2 #] & /@ list]
```